# Системный выбор радиоботтнона или "как заставить поользователя выбрать"

Tags: javascript, css, radio, ucoz

Есть форма (в самом конце) и вопрос по выбору радиокнопок.
Можно ли как то модернизировать ссылку  (по такому адресу находится форма) чтобы при переходе по ссылке 1 в блоке с радиокнопками выбирался (со всеми последующими действиями, что происходят при клике) радиокнопка "G", а при переходе по ссылке 2 в блоке с радиокнопками выбирался (со всеми последующими действиями, что происходят при клике) радиокнопка "F". Но, при этом вынести форму на другую страницу нельзя, адрес —

Comment: а это тут не причем,если первый малореализуемый,то второй думаю можно.ч пробовал на css с атрибутом checked,но не получилось

Comment: * Здесь не принято задавать одинаковые вопросы несколько раз. Если предыдущие ответы не устраивают, можно редактировать вопрос или уточнять в комментариях)

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Передаете ссылке какой-нибудь параметр, например, `/index/3?selectedOption=1`, а яваскрипт после загрузки страницы его считывает ([тут](https://usefulangle.com/post/78/javascript-get-url-parameters) описано как) и выбирает нужные элементы формы .

В псевдокоде:

```
if(script.parsed.url.parameter.selectedOption == '1') {
  yourForm.abvcheck.setAttribute('checked', 'true')
}
else {...}
```

Comment: Если будет 2 радио и айди нужного abvcheck то как это должно выглядеть?

Comment: @Ivan Два одинаковых id по определению не должно быть) Если будет - сработает первый.

Comment: добавил в ответ

Comment: Это значит "Если не выполнится предыдущее условие и кусок кода внутри него, то выполнить вот это: ...". Троеточие - некий код, если он вам вообще нужен.

Comment: скриптом, например, так: jsfiddle.net/oe920pdh/ ; чтобы стилями, надо чтобы блок был после радиокнопки на том же уровне вложенности или ниже, а у вас там намешано...